# Using a loop to execute several yarn scripts

Tags: bash, loops

I am trying to bootstrap a pseudo CI to run manually, and I am refactoring my basic bash script from :

```
echo '=========> yarn format <========='
yarn format

echo '=========> yarn test:cov <========='
yarn test:cov

echo '=========> yarn test:inte <========='
yarn test:inte

echo echo '=========> yarn test:e2e <========='
yarn test:e2e

echo '=========> yarn build <========='
yarn build
```

to

```
#!/bin/zsh
scripts=(
  'yarn format'
  'yarn test:cov'
  'yarn test:inte'
  'yarn test:e2e'
  'yarn build'
)

for script in "${scripts[@]}"
do
  printf '\n=========> %s <=========\n' "$script"
  $script
done
```

But, if the first script works perfectly fine, the loop version gives this result as an output :

```
➜  back git:(refactor/remove-decoupling) ✗ yarn ci
$ ./tmtc-ci.sh

=========> yarn format <=========
./tmtc-ci.sh:13: command not found: yarn format

=========> yarn test:cov <=========
./tmtc-ci.sh:13: command not found: yarn test:cov

=========> yarn test:inte <=========
./tmtc-ci.sh:13: command not found: yarn test:inte

=========> yarn test:e2e <=========
./tmtc-ci.sh:13: command not found: yarn test:e2e

=========> yarn build <=========
./tmtc-ci.sh:13: command not found: yarn build
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
➜  back git:(refactor/remove-decoupling) ✗
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found the answer to my question :

`eval "$script"`

as my array of scripts holds only strings as I understand it.